# What is scope of class annotated with @Singleton in Mortar

Tags: java, android, dagger, object-graph, mortar

How does Mortar handle classes annotated with `@Singleton`? To clarify, when I use Dagger and have an `Activity` graph plus'd into the `Application` graph on every activity create, I also get an activity scoped singleton of any class that is annotated with `@Singleton` that do not have a provides method in any module.

If I instead start using Mortar and defining a `MortarScope` for each screen, is there a way I can scope things to a screen without explicitly having to create a provides for them?  My reason for not wanting to include a `Provides` is to be able to inject other objects into my activity helper instances without having to manually set fields from the constructor.